# How to calculate battery lifetime from datasheet

Tags: cell

I wanted to understand how one can model the lifetime of a cell when it supplies power to a step-up converter.

For this question, I want to focus on two products. Tadiran [TL-4930](https://www.atbatt.com/content/TL-4930.pdf) cell and Adafruit [PowerBoost](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-powerboost-1000c-load-share-usb-charge-boost/overview). Assume that a constant power load is connected to the output node of the step-up converter and consumes 1W continuously. Also, assume that the power efficiency of the converter is 90%.

In this case I should expect that the input power to the converter is 1.25W. But I have no idea how to calculate the terminal voltage and the output current of the TL-4830 at the room temperature. Is there a reliable way of estimating the voltage and current under a certain condition? Let's assume the cell has the full capacity.

Another question is, if the cell temperature is -40 degrees Celsius, how do you estimate the voltage and current?

The last question is, is it possible to estimate the voltage, current as function of T and Q?

Comment: > is it possible to estimate the voltage, current as function of T and Q?  Yes but you need more than 1 cell.. Work out the results from datasheet

Comment: What is lifetime? How many years you can use it?

Answer (score 1):

The battery you selected has a nominal voltage of 3.6V and a **maximum** continuous current of 100mA, so you can't get more than 360mW from this battery continuously. So this battery won't work for you at all.

In general, you need to rely on the information in the datasheet about a battery's capacity under specific conditions of current and temperature.